# partialFunction in collectFirst

Tags: scala, collect, partialfunction

I have a sequence of some objects and I want to collect the first
element for which another function returns Some()

For now, my code works this way:

```
mySeq.collectFirst{
  case elem if doSmth(elem).nonEmpty => 
    (doSmth(elem).get, elem)
}
```

Is there a way to:

1. Refactor it not to call doSmth twice?
2. change this code to log smth in case doSmth returns None

```
res.match {
  case Some(v) => v
  case None => log.info("Searching further...")//partial function doesn't match
}
```

I would say, the main question is - is it possible to create a PartialFunction that matches all cases, but for some of the cases we do produce some side effect (log message in this case) and explicitly say that it is not matched?

Edit:

I am wondering, why would the following code throw an error when I run tests (not compilation error though)

```
mySeq.collectFirst{
case elem => 
  val r: Option[Int] = doSmth(elem)
  r match {
    case Some(res) => res
  }
}
```

Comment: May I ask what bothers you with the `if` statement?

Comment: It looks a bit... ugly, I don't know.

I mean, we have if and under it we have match that catches the other case of if

It looks unnatural

Comment: I think it is bad idea to use `collectFirst` and `partial function` with side-effects as well as try to pass function witch should be defined for all inputs as `partial function`. Try to clarify what do you want to do with seq? Do you want to `find` some element? or maybe you want to iterate on elements and do something?

Comment: I wanted to get the first element for which doSmth returns not None. The logging part is not that important, actually. I wanted to see if it is possible not to call doSmth() twice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, there may be a way to not call `doSmth` twice and log the empties, but that would look pretty ugly (you'd have to subclass `PartialFunction` explicitly, spell out `isDefined`, and have a `var` member to keep the result).

Overall, this is just not a good use case for `collectFirst`. Just do something like this instead:

```
   mySeq
     .view
     .map(doSmth)
     .flatMap { 
       case None => 
         log("nope")
         None
       case x => x
     }.headOption
```

Or if you are like me, and prefer a series of short transformations chained together to one monolithic function, here's a fancy way:

```
   mySeq
    .view
    .map(doSmth)
    .map(_.toRight(println("searching")))
    .collectFirst { case Right(x) => x }
```

Comment: Could you please explain, why the code I mentioned in the post would not work?
When I run tests. I get an exception

Comment: @DArtem Assuming you are talking about the last snippet in your post, that partial function is defined everywhere, so when `r` is `None` it throws because you don't have a matching `case` for it.

Comment: Ok, I thought that I could define a partial function that way. I think it was my mistake

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom pattern matcher for this. This is an object with an `unapply` method that can be used in a pattern match.

This code will do the same as the original, but will only call `doSmth` once:

```
object MatchSomething {
  def unapply[T](elem: T): Option[(String, T)] =
    doSmth(elem).map(r => (r, elem))
}

mySeq.collectFirst {
  case MatchSomething((smth, elem)) =>
    (smth, elem)
}
```

You can log the failed matches in the `unapply` method:

```
object MatchSomething {
  def unapply[T](elem: T): Option[(String, T)] =
    doSmth(elem) match {
      case Some(r) =>
        Some((r, elem))
      case None =>
        println(s"$elem did not match, searching further")
        None
    }
}
```